# High RAM and CPU consumption by this process

Tags: process, cpu, firefox, ram

I have 4GB RAM on my computer and I could see using this command:

```
ps aux --sort=-%mem | awk 'NR<=10{print $0}'
```

that this process consumes a lot of memory and cpu:

```
/usr/lib/firefox/plugin-container -greomni /usr/lib/firefox/omni.ja -appomni /usr/lib/firefox/browser/omni.ja -appdir /usr/lib/firefox/browser 463 tab
```

And, in the second place, follows `firefox` process.

I do not know if I can do something to avoid or reduce the RAM's consumption. I appreciate your help. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Kill all the firefox processes and try a Chromium-based browser.
If you really **have** to stay on FF, then try to reduce the amount of things like tabs, plugins, etc. loaded in your firefox session.

Comment: Yes, I really need to stay on FF. The strange thing is that I do not have a lot of things like tabs, etc. Only 5 tabs, and one extension (ad block).

Comment: I changed this parameter: `layers.acceleration.force-enabled` for true in `about:config` of FF. And now memory available decreases and cpu increases a little, but is fine because it works everything better.

Comment: In my experience sometimes a single tab, that loaded a badly made website, could cause some high memory/cpu usage.